# Creating a sub class that doesn't uses super constructor automatically

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, extends

I've got several classes:

```
import java.io.File;
public interface Filter {

    public boolean passes();

}
```

```
import java.io.File;

abstract public class PFilter implements Filter {
    String val;
    File file;


    public PFilter(String value, File f){
        val = value;
        file = f;
    }
    @Override
    abstract public boolean passes();

}
```

and at last;

```
import java.io.File;

public class HFilter extends PFilter {
    public HFilter(String val, File f) {
        super(value, f);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean passes() {
        return file.isHidden();
    }
}
```

I'd like to if it's possible for me to not call `super()` in the `HFilter` class. Is it possible then when creating an instance of HFilter, once I put in the two arguments It will automatically call the `super()` and then I wont need a constructor?

Comment: *Is it possible then when ... It will automatically call the super() and then I wont need a constructor?* => No. When you replace the default constructor from the superclass, the compiler expects you to call super explicitly.

Comment: So, no matter what, I'll have to define the same exact constructor for Hfilter and then call super? It just kind of seems weird. The class knows its an extension, so shouldn't it understand which constructor it needs?

Comment: No necessarily.  You can have what ever constructor you want for `Hfilter` but the first method call in the constructor has to satisfy super's constructor

Comment: @ernest_k missed your edit. making sure - It doesn't make sense for the superclass to have a default constructor, so, I shouldn't create one just to get the functionality I'm looking for?

Comment: @Omri.B The thing is that you have data being passed to the constructor, so your non-default constructor has a reason for being. Constructors are unfortunately not inherited/overridden, so you'll have to replicate the constructor (if the values must be set by a constructor)

Comment: I understand, `super()` it is then. Thanks a bunch!